# Save String with random number of lines to single line array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, split

So here is the method which is reading from the file, it then splits the information by the @ sign. which is where a new month begins in the text file

```
public static String readPurchaseOrder(Scanner sc) {

    final String DELIMITER = "@";
    try {           
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            sc.useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
            String data = sc.next();               
            return data;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    sc.close(); 
    return null;
}
```

The text file contains information shown below up to the 12th month

```
  04/01/12#PNW-1234#PA/1234#10
    15/01/12#BSE-5566#bT/4674#5@
    08/02/12#PNE-3456#Xk/8536#1@
    07/03/12#PEA-4567#ZR/7413#3
    09/03/12#ESE-6329#HY/7195#30@
    03/04/12#ESE-5577#LR/4992#12
    23/04/12#PNW-1235#HY/7195#2@
    09/05/12#ESE-6329#PV/5732#6
    25/05/12#BSE-5566#PV/5732#10@
    08/06/12#PNE-3457#kD/9767#1
    31/06/12#EMI-6329#ZR/7413#10@
    03/07/12#EMI-6329#PV/5732#12
    25/07/12#BSE-5566#bT/4674#5@
```

I am using this to output the information from the file split by the @

```
 for (int i = 0; i <12; i ++){
          String str[] = InputFileData.readPurchaseOrder(sC).split("\\n");
          for(String s : str){
              System.out.println(s);
          }
```

It outputs the data like this

```
04/01/12#PNW-1234#PA/1234#10
15/01/12#BSE-5566#bT/4674#5

08/02/12#PNE-3456#Xk/8536#1

07/03/12#PEA-4567#ZR/7413#3
09/03/12#ESE-6329#HY/7195#30

03/04/12#ESE-5577#LR/4992#12
23/04/12#PNW-1235#HY/7195#2

09/05/12#ESE-6329#PV/5732#6
25/05/12#BSE-5566#PV/5732#10
```

I want to store each individual line in an array, so I can then further split up the line to its each respective variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to collect the results in an array, one line per array element, the easiest way to do it is to use a list (since you don't know in advance the number of lines), and then convert it to an array. The size of an array has to be declared in advance, so you want to use a more flexible data structure if you don't know how big it's going to be.

```
public static String[] readPurchaseOrder(Scanner sc) {
    final String DELIMITER = "@";
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        try {           
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                sc.useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
                String data = sc.next();               
                results.add(data);  // add the line to the list
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        sc.close(); 
        // convert the list to an array and return it.
        return results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
    }
```

Comment: Does `return results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);` return a String?

Comment: oops. no. :) I will fix

Comment: Maybe add a bit of explanation to the OP and this would be a good answer.

Comment: dude. you are a tough task master. but sure ... :)

Comment: how do i return just the results array?

Comment: @Shane  We are returning an array with the results. If you would like to return the ArrayList<String> called results, then change the return type to List<String> and the last line to: return results;

Comment: once i have returned the array to the main method, how do i then break it down into months then each line then split each value on the line by #

Comment: You can split on # just as you split on @.   Just call it on each line.  I think I've probably gone as far as I can without solving this homework problem entirely.